# Why not import Python

Tags: python, import, relative-path

There's this app structure, where `myapp` is the root directory and "app" and "package1" two parallel packages:

```
myapp

  app
     __init__.py
     app.py

  package1
     __init__.py
     my_file.py
 
  __init__.py
```

*Note: the last `__init__.py` is located in the root directory "myapp"

Now, in the **app.py**, if I try to **import** the **my_file.py**

```
from ..package1 import my_file as my_variable
```

Then I get this error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I've researched and found a possible solution here:

[How to resolve **ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package**](https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent)

I'd like to apply the "Solution 1", but don't understand exactly **where** should I put the **main.py** and which would be its **internal code** or if, conversely, it could be an empty file like `__init__.py`

Answer (score 2):

You should have a `run` function in `app.py`:

```
def run():
    # .... You code that should run as app
```

There should be no automatic running code in `app.py`

`main.py` should be on the same folder as `myapp`:

```
myapp
  app
     __init__.py
     app.py

  package1
     __init__.py
     my_file.py

  __init__.py
main.py
```

Now `main.py` should contain something like this:

```
from myapp.app import app

app.run()
```

and you can run it `python main.py`

Alternative you can  also put a `__main__.py` file in `myapp`:

```
myapp
  app
     __init__.py
     app.py

  package1
     __init__.py
     my_file.py

  __init__.py
  __main__.py
```

The `__main__.py` should contain something like this:

```
from .app import app

app.run()
```

The you cann run it like this `python -m myapp`